# Error While Deploying React application on server

Tags: reactjs, deployment, windows-server, npm-start, run-script

i am getting error while **running application on server**
it is properly working on local i just enter Run (npm start) and perfectly running on local.
but same thing i am doing on server i am getting the error given below.
please someone help me out.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:646:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! chakde11@1.0.0 build-css: `node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the chakde11@1.0.0 build-css script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-30T06_54_54_535Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! chakde11@1.0.0 watch-css: `npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the chakde11@1.0.0 watch-css script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-30T06_54_54_566Z-debug.log
ERROR: "watch-css" exited with 1.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! chakde11@1.0.0 start: `npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the chakde11@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-30T06_54_54_800Z-debug.log
```

{
  "name": "chakde11",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": false,
  "homepage": "http://chakde11.com/",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "d3-geo": "^1.10.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "jsx": "^0.9.89",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "package.json": "^2.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^0.14.9",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.2",
    "react-component-queries": "^2.3.0",
    "react-countdown-now": "^2.1.0",
    "react-countdown-to-future-date": "0.0.3",
    "react-d3-map": "^0.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-ga": "^2.5.3",
    "react-icons": "^2.2.7",
    "react-infinite-calendar": "^2.3.1",
    "react-notification-system": "^0.2.17",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-simple-maps": "^0.12.1",
    "react-sizeme": "^2.5.2",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.3.1",
    "reactjs-countdown": "0.0.8",
    "reactstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "victory": "^0.27.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^1.2.0",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "serve": "^9.1.0",
    "stylelint": "^9.3.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "^3.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^0.8.1",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
    "serve": "serve -s build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}

Comment: What's your build script? Did you deploy your static site to the server or simply run node scripts? Di you run 'npm install'?

Comment: i run npm install, then npm start inside the domain folder. yes i am deploying static site to server, do i need to change any file or code? i have changed the homepage: ''MyURL" inside the package.json file.

Comment: You probably need to post your package.json file.

Comment: yes i just added the package.json code below the question

Comment: @MattYao i have posted my package.json.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check your package.json file "start" script and perhaps change the command to:

```
"start": "NODE_PATH=./src npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
```

I found the same issue as yours: https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-material-dashboard-pro-react/issues/69